# How to get a specialized Django model instance when querying its base class?

Tags: python, django

I have a classic use case for Django [multi-table model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), in an app that manages remote hosts.

The app can work with generic "RemoteHost", or "SshHost" (that is also a RemoteHost), or "EsxiHost" (that is also a SshHost), so naturally I went for multi-table model inheritance:

```
class RemoteHost(models.Model):
    ...
    def shutdown(self):
        raise NotImplemented()

class SshHost(RemoteHost):
    ...
    def shutdown(self):
        # run SSH shutdown command

class EsxiHost(SshHost):
    ...
    def shutdown(self):
        # shutdown running virtual machine using VMware API
        SshHost(self).shutdown()
```

I want to be able to "shutdown" managed hosts without knowing the specific host type, e.g. `RemoteHost.objects.get(pk=1).shutdown()`, but it turns out that Django data model will return the explicitly requested type (per my experience, as well as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested)).

I am looking for a clean way to obtain the most specialized instance available based on a base-class queryset.

So far, the "cleanest" approach I came up with looks something like this:

```
class RemoteHost(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_specialized_instance(self):
        try:
            return self.sshhost.get_specialized_instance()
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return self

class SshHost(RemoteHost):
    ...
    def get_specialized_instance(self):
        try:
            return self.esxihost.get_specialized_instance()
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return self

class EsxiHost(SshHost):
    ...
    def get_specialized_instance(self):
        return self
```

The upside of this approach is that it works :-)

But I don't like it for the following reasons:

1. It requires the using code the explicitly call `get_specialized_instance()` on objects.
2. It requires that the base models know about the models that extend them.

So, any advice on a better / cleaner way to achieve this will be welcome!

Comment: see `related` section to the right, aswer it seems is right there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349206/how-do-i-find-the-concrete-class-of-a-django-model-baseclass?rq=1

Comment: [Django Polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) could be your friend here, instead of writing your own ObjectManagers and setting ContentTypes, it does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @professorDante: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!
Just need to keep in mind that it inflicts DB overhead...

Semi-meta - why did you answer this as a comment instead of an answer? I can't flag it as "answer" this way...

Comment: Updated to give it as an answer! It's not too onerous to do it yourself btw - I'm using [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1034/) snippet for one of my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django Polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic) could be your friend here, instead of writing your own ObjectManagers and setting ContentTypes, it does all the heavy lifting for you. There you go, a proper answer! :-)